# Why the code below doesn't generate "segmentation fault" on windows?

Tags: segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void bad() {
    printf("Oh shit really bad~!\r\n");
}

void foo() {
    char overme[4] = "WOW";
    *(int*)(overme+8) = (int)bad;
}

int main() {
   foo();
}
```

In 32bit linux it generates segmentation fault,but in windows not.Why?

Answer (score 4):

Because undefined behaviour means *exactly* that: undefined. Not defined-but-will-cause-error, but *undefined,* meaning that anything can happen.

And sometimes that *anything* may be that it works as expected. That doesn't make it a good thing, of course, since it may *stop* working as expected with a new compiler or operating system or runtime library or even based on the day of the week or phase of the moon.

The ISO standards mandate how a well defined program will behave, they do not mandate how an undefined one will, other than to say it can do anything it darn well pleases.

For the specific case, you would have to examine the assembler code generated by the compiler to see why it's not trashing your stack. It's possible that Linux stores a rather vital piece of information at the location you're overwriting (like the return address from `main`) while Windows stores something relatively benign (like the return code from `main`).

Comment: Shouldn't the address before `bp` always be the return address?

Comment: No. The standard has nothing to say about the calling convention used or where things are located on the stack or even if a bp register even exists :-) I answered an earlier question where the stack was vastly different using exactly the same compiler and everything else other than the optimisation level: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536564/stack-layout-for-process/5536611#5536611

Comment: I'm doubting whether segmentation fault ever happens on windows?

Comment: @compile-fan: Happens all the time, write to random addresses nowhere near any valid addresses.  Windows calls it an "Access Violation" though.  Looks like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/49/Windows_null_ptr_dereference.png